How to reuse return types across queries in sqlc
As I understand in sqlc.yaml the overrides key is relevent for overriding individual columns.
What if I have two distinct queries that say generate the following functions: ListSongs and SearchSongs, but they both should return a struct with the same fields. sqlc generates two different row structs even though they have the same fields. I don't want to resort to using empty interfaces or generics in the client code. Is there a best-practice to cover this case?

If the structs are identical you can use a conversion. Note that there are already multiple open issues re this (1 2), so opening another is probably not necessary.

Thanks, I guess I will have to type convert for now. Not so pretty, but it should work without resorting to empty interfaces and type casting.

So it turns out the two queries weren't returning the same exact fields. Once I modified them to return the same exact fields using SELECT then sqlc was smart enough to use the same return type.

What version of sqlc were you using for this to happen automatically?

version: 1.17.0

If the select matches a table, you can use sqlc embeding which will give you one object per table row in your query. Here is an example from the documentation:
https://docs.sqlc.dev/en/stable/howto/embedding.html

With embedding, the struct will contain a model for both tables
instead of a flattened list of columns.

-- name: ScoreAndTests :many
SELECT sqlc.embed(students), sqlc.embed(test_scores)
FROM students
JOIN test_scores ON test_scores.student_id = students.id
WHERE students.id = $1;

type ScoreAndTestsRow struct {
    Student   Student
    TestScore TestScore
}

